# Setting up PyODE in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I've been trying to set up Py-ODE in Anaconda (32-bit for a Windows 7 64-bit machine and Python 2.7) and it's been an insane pain in the arse so to speak. Py-ODE from what I see on their website is only available for Python 2.6 so I set up an environment using conda specifically for it. When I tried to run the setup for Py-ODE it gives the warning " not found. You may have to adjust INC_DIRS." and shortly exits with "error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

I know there is a post about vcvarsall.bat but I already have visual C++ 2008 installed and it just seems like a super long workaround.

I then tried to install with the PyODE executable snapshot but that also did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be Py-ODE? If not, you could also think about [PyDSTool](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/ProjectOverview.html) which also allows you to do bifurcation analysis or also [PySCeS](http://pysces.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I'm looking for tool to help me visually display the utilities of pybrain - there was some demo code I found but it needed PyODE. If you have any tools that I could use with ANN's just to get a visual aspect going let me know (like creature evolution...)

Comment: Would you mind posting this demo code/an example, and explaining in more detail what you want to do with it? That would make it easier to look for a solution to your problem. For me it is not fully clear what you mean by "utilities of pybrain", what exactly you want to do with ANN. So please be as precise as possible :)

Comment: This is the video I was referring to - https://vimeo.com/12914367. At the 20:00 mark there is a 3d virtual robot learning to grasp a cup using a pybrain ANN. I'd like to get an existing project working and play around with that as a means of learning more about pybrain and neural nets. This one has some cool examples as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEM7YDNonSE.